# Should I copy all my JavaScript sources into one single file?

Tags: javascript, performance, loading

In a current web project, I'm using several jQuery plugins and initializing them just before the closing body tag. My question is, from a loading time/performance standpoint, would it be best for me to take all such initializations and copy them into a single, externalized js file? the plugins are being initialized in the same way within all pages in the site, so it would seem loading one, centralized file would be best, no? thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on what you are developing for, but here are some rules of thumb.

HTTP requests mean overhead (especially over HTTPS) so try to make as little as possible, for mobile this is crucial. there are a few exceptions though; lazy loading JavaScript files which aren't needed when the app initializes is sometimes smart so they're cached when really needed, using a CDN for popular libs sometimes can lead to great performance boost because of paralel downloads.

keep downloads as small as possible, so minify all JavaScript and CSS, some even minify HTML.

make sure cache headers are set correctly (some set them to a year or more), and when a new version of your script is deployed, append the src attribute of the script element with a version number to counter caching, like: `<script src="myapp.js?v=2"></script>`

Sometimes perceived performance is better than real performance, meaning; having the HTML loaded and rendered is more important than the application initialized. this can be done by asynchronously loading JavaScript files (by inserting script elements with JavaScript like Google does or by using script loaders which do this for you). but this leads to new challenges like the execution order of loaded files or interacting with the page before the script files are fully loaded and parsed.

In the end it's heavily dependent on the architecture of your online app or site and what the interaction with it is or should be, care to elaborate further by giving some examples?

PM5544.

Comment: thanks for the great feedback PM5544. I'm particularly curious to learn more about asynchronous js loading to boost performance. Here is an example of a small site I did for a friend to display his artwork: http://tinyurl.com/758ocgo  I'm using a few jQuery plugins and would be curious to hear if there's anything I should be doing differently to optimize performance.

Comment: In this specific case i would advise you to do the following; combine the plugins into one JavaScipt file than minify it. move all the `<script>` elements to the bottom of the page and put the Google analtytics all the way at the bottom. combine all css files and remove all useless whitespace (tabs and enters) and combine all functions which run on DOMReady into one function.

Comment: One comment here about myapp.js?v=2 - in some browsers this may mean the browser will not cache your JS. It's better to have myapp.2.js as the filename and have your webserver simply fetch myapp.js

Answer (score 1):

Any significant quantity of javascript code is better off in a common externalized javascript file because it can be cached more efficiently between all your pages.

A few lines of code inline in the page before the closing body tag to call some initialization code in an externalized javascript file is perfectly fine and doesn't slow anything down if that's the best way to trigger the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can *minify* JavaScript and CSS into single files using tools like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/). But putting *all* of your assets into single files can be troublesome: If the files are large, the browser can only use a single TCP stream to download them, versus multiple simultaneous requests. Read more about this here: [Loading JavaScript Resources the Fun Way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff943568)

As for *where* to put the `<script>` tags in your HTML, the answer is at the bottom of the page before the closing `</body>` tag. Check out Google's [Web Performance Best Practices](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html) site.